# applying regular expression for text highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jqxDataAdapter](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdataadapter/jquery-data-adapter.htm) for jqxWidgets in my code as follows:

```
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {

            loadComplete: function (records) {
                var html;
                var color = '#F3F315';

                //Get data
                var records = dataAdapter.records;
                var length = records.length;
                console.log("Checking Length: "+length);// Outputs 5
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                console.log("checking Words here: " +records[i].word_text);// Displays five words in the console log one 
                }


                html = "<div style='margin: 10px;'><pre>" + records[1].note_content + "</pre></div>"; //records[1].note_content  shows a long paragraph of text with words to highlight

   // Is this correct way to apply regular expression?
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                    html = html.replace(new RegExp(records[i].word_text, 'ig'), '<span style="background-color:' + color + ';">' + records[i].word_text + '</span>');
                }




                console.log("How many span tags you are noticing here?: " + html);
                $("#docContent").html(html);
            },
            loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { },
            beforeLoadComplete: function (records) {

            }
        });
```

I am wondering, is the regular expression applied correctly because, every where in the document, I am noticing the words that needs to be highlighted are surrounded by two `<span>` tags. For example,
`<span style="background-color:#F3F315;"><span style="background-color:#F3F315;">CAR</span></span>`

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg9nccde/9/) which will give you some idea what's going on but it doesn't have the above code in it. Words are getting highlighted but I don't understand the reason behind two span tags getting added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both lowercase and uppercase words in your test array:

```
var data = [{
    name: 'CAR'
}, {
    name: 'Car'
}, {
    name: 'Bus'
}, {
    name: 'BUS'
}, {
```

And your regex is **case insensitive**, which is what the `i` is in the list of flags you use:

```
new RegExp(records[i].word_text, 'ig')
```

This means the loop will match `CAR` against `car` (case insensitive), wrap it in a span, then match `Car` against `car` (again case insensitive) and wrap it in a second span.

You either want to match the specific case of the words in the test array by removing the `i` flag and keep the `g` (global):

```
new RegExp(records[i].word_text, 'g')
```

Or you want to remove the duplicate case entries from your array and keep the `i` flag, so words aren't matched more than once.